# libGL segfault на машине с картой nvidia

Tags: linux, centos, nvidia, segmentation-fault

Имеется Fedora 24 (да, такая древняя :) ) и приложение c glut и еще другими либами по медиа.
На большинстве машин заказчика живет нормально. На парочке, где есть карта nvidia валится с такой ошибкой (кордамп при аборте)

**segfault at a38 ip 00007fa240f25bc9 sp 00007fa2063fd8a8 error 4 in libGL.so.340.98[7fa240f15000+2f000]**

как оно вообще так выходит, что компилится под libGL.so.1, а пользуется в итоге какую-то версию от дров? Ну и что можно сделать тут?

Comment: а какие дрова для видяхи стоят на машине где падает?

Comment: nvidia-smi =  390.116

Comment: Закрыта тема, в итоге, после детализации, проблема оказалась в разнопотоковом использовании glGenTextures и glDeleteTextures